# Dimension of covariant and contravariant vectors on a manifold

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory

I don't really know if the question is too stupid to be answered, so I apologize in advance, but I'm really confused about it.

I did an introductory course in General Relativity and studied hard for it, so I should be familar with these concepts, but turns out that I'm actually not.

Consider for example a field $\boldsymbol{\phi}:\mathcal{M}_n\to\Phi\subseteq\mathbb{R}^p$ defined on a manifold, with generic dimension. What really confuses me a lot is the fact that this field is usually treated having the same $n$ dimension of the manifold, especially when there is to define its covariant and contravariant components.

I don't really know why: is there a reason for it?
Because I imagine the "coordinates" $\boldsymbol{x}$ on the manifold to be just continuos indices; *I don't really get why a quantity that gets indices should have the same dimensions of them!*

Thanks for help, Rob

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing a field defined on the manifold with a choice of coordinates [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)#Charts)? I would expect a field to be $\phi:\mathcal M\rightarrow \Phi\in\Bbb R$, no?

Comment: The vectors in a vector field $\vec v(P)$ defined on a manifold $M$ are usually assumed to be members of the tangent space at each point i.e. $\vec v(P) \in T_P$, and each tangent space has the same dimension as $M$ itself.

Comment: @Charlie I just considered the more general case of a vector field, like usually in quantum field theory. Sorry, but I don't understand your question!

Comment: @gandalf61 Yes, that's what I was taught about. But my question actually is: "has sense to define covariant and contravariant component of a $p$-dimensional vector in an $n(\neq p)$-dimensional manifold?" That's the question

Comment: @Rob No, that makes no sense to me. I think you need to review your understanding of vector fields, convector fields and tensor fields. The key fact is that the tangent space and the cotangent space at each point of a manifold always have the same dimension as that manifold. The concepts of contravariance and covariance simply do not work otherwise.

Comment: @gandalf61 Thanks for the answer, in a way I also agree with what you say. But what can I deduce from it: that if I am in a 4-dimensional spacetime I cannot talk about covariance and contravariance of tridimensional vector? How can I concile that with Lorentz transformations? I mean for example electromagnetic field seems to have not covariant and contravariant coordinates (just in the sense of euclidean metric maybe, but they are equal), but at the same time it ichanges with lorentz transformation even if it is not a four-dimensional field! How's that possible?!